# Schedule refresh in power BI

Tags: powerbi

When I try to schedule a refresh a last time, it doesn't work since there have been the update in **power BI**. Can you help me about that please ?

Tanks !

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow,  help us help you by asking a question in the right way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It may help to show what you have tried, some example data, or screenshots and expected outcomes

Comment: You mention scheduled refresh since the last update? Do you mean desktop?

Comment: Yeah PB desktop.

Comment: Scheduled refresh isn't in desktop, it is only in the service